# Why is Visual Studio not coloring the most of the text?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Hello I just started programming with Unity but each time I open a new C# script Visual Studio colors only a few of the words which are given by the launch. I saw in a video that

```
public class (name of script) : MonoBehaviour
```

has to be colored but `monoBehaviour` isn't colored.[image] [image][image]

Comment: Were they using addons in the video (e.g. Resharper?) And did you check your colour settings in `Tools | Options | Fonts and Colors`?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. A print screen of what you have might be useful for us to better understand what problem you have. Changing the color theme might also help you can go to `Tools->Options->Environment->General` and pick a different color theme.

Comment: no my fonts and colors are on default and words like: public class controlls are colored only some words aren´t

Comment: and my general is on dark I dont think that the problem is there.

Comment: It could be your VS setup, or VS not detecting it is  Unity Project, or your Unity Project having code errors (somewhere else) that you have not fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be because it needs to be MonoBehaviour rather than monoBehaviour? The lack of capitalisation probably causes it to not find the MonoBehaviour class

Comment: no i wrote it wrong it is MonoBehaviour

Answer (score 2):

It might be because, Visual Studio is detecting the `.CS` file as a normal `.cs` file rather then a Unity project, now to check weather this is the case or not? In Visual Studio at the top of your code window it should say `Assembly-CSharp` just below the tabs. Please take a look at bellow.

[image]

If this is the case you just have to is

1. Close the unity
2. Delete all the `.csproj` files.
3. You can find those files in the folder of your Project. To Open the root folder

   - Right Click on `Assets` folder in your project panel.
   - Then select `Open in Explorer` or `show in finder` for MAC.
   - Now at the bottom you will see all the `.csProj` Files. Delete them
4. Reopen the project.

And Unity Will regenerate all the `.csproj` files. Open the scripts and check in Visual Studio.

Comment: I added a pic. of my code can you look at it.

Comment: i´m not shure if it is wrong

Comment: I can see that you Visual Studio is not Detecting your files as Unity Project files

Comment: Did you deleted all the .csproj File, and reopened the project in Unity?

Comment: I am not shure I Deleted everything that came when i searched for .csproj

Comment: I don't realy know where These files are stored.

Comment: I've added new instructions for that in my answer please check

Comment: It didn't helped it is still wrong

Comment: I tryed to delete all my unity folders but it is still not working

Comment: Ok, Make sure you have Visual Studio selected as External Editor in ```Unity > Preference > External Tools```

Comment: And also make sure that you have Visual Studio Unity extension installed in Visual Studio.

Comment: Whats that extension and where do i download it

Comment: [Get started with Visual Studio Tools for Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2019) Please take a look at above link.

Comment: I did it but there is still Miscellaneous Files. It didn't change anything.

Comment: show me the screenshots of the external-tools settings, from the preference

Comment: I edited a pic. at the question. The Visual Studio I added to the script editor is my Visual studio I am using right Now I Browsed and selected it.

Comment: Looks ok, now open the extension window in Visual studio. And tell me do you see Unity extension there?

Comment: No there is only manage extension and Customizing Menü...

Comment: Open the Visual Studio Installer then click on Modify, Install the Unity plugin for VisualStudio

Comment: I allready did. I aded a picture at the question.

Comment: I Downloaded anotherone too might this be the problem

Comment: Oh dear, I'm afraid that I don't have anything to say here. Your settings look correct and I don't why Visual Studio is not able to do what it suppose to do. Try installing an LTS version of unity and then open the project from there. This might be a bug from the unity side.

Comment: Ok thanks for Helping me this far

Comment: I did it. I installed the 2017 Version of visual studio and it is working

Comment: Congratulations, to you my friend finally you did it.

Comment: @Ankit Thank you very match!!! I used your link and installed the needed extensions. Later I also needed to use this link https://forum.unity.com/threads/assembly-csharp-editor-csproj-could-not-be-loaded-because-it-doesnt-exist.529663/  (visual studio noted me that "Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj could not be loaded - Because it doesn't exist")